# Adding an instance of NFData for MongoDB Document

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to run some computations concurrently with forkIO and in each thread I want to write a MongoDB [Document](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bson/0.1.7/doc/html/Data-Bson.html#t%3aDocument). Because I want the computation to actually be done on the thread I want to fully evaluate this Document, so I'm using Strict MVars.

However, when I'm trying this I get

```
No instance for (NFData Field)
  arising from a use of `putMVar'
```

Which means (I assume) I need to add an instance declaration for Document for this to be evaluated.

Unfortunately, because the structure of the Document is kind of complex, I'm not sure how to do this.

I'm generally unfamiliar with NFData and how to make instance of it as well so I don't really how to start doing this.

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing an instance of `NFData` shouldn't be too hard, but it can be awfully repetitive for types with a complex structure. As your `Document` type is a synonym for `[Field]`, and `Control.DeepSeq` already exports `instance NFData a => NFData [a]`, you really need an instance for `Field`.

With the [`deepseq-th`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-th-0.1.0.2) package, you can use Template Haskell to derive an instance automatically, saving you the tedium:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.DeepSeq.TH

import Data.Bson

deriveNFData ''Field
```

And that should do it.

Comment: Just adding a note for future viewers (if any) that I did not get this to work with Haskell-Platform at the time of writing this, because the version of GHC that is released with haskell-platform has base 4.3.* and deepseeq-th required base 4.4.*. I.E. you have to install a newer version of GHC.

Comment: The author recommends `deepseq-generics` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-generics) as an alternative "for a less experimental approach" (from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-th-0.1.0.4), which is based on `GHC.Generics` rather than Template Haskell.